# Auto Lisp How to select items inside block and get Volume

Tags: lisp, autocad, autolisp

How to get Volume of 3D Solids inside a Block using Auto Lisp

```
                                   (setq Teset
                                      (ssget "X"
                                         (list (cons 8 Layerdname));;;;;;;;;;;;;Select the Blocks from the Main Layer
                                      )
                                   )




                                   (setq Tcntr 0)
                                   (setq Ttvm 0)

                                            (setq Ten (ssname Teset 0))
                                            (setq Tvlaobj (vlax-ename->vla-object Ten))

                                            (setq Tobjs (vla-Explode Tvlaobj))
                            ..............Help here Please.............

                                            (princ Tobjs)

                                        (princ)
```

In this Code 
adding the items on a layer to selection set and explode the first entity which is a block.

and i need to select all objects in that exploded block (all are 3d Solids) and print the volume

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After:

```
(setq Tobjs (vla-explode block ) )
```

You can get volume by:

```
(setq ObjectsAsList (vlax-safearray->list (vlax-variant-value Tobjs ) ) )
(foreach % ObjectsAsList    
    (setq volume (vlax-get-property % 'volume ) )   
    (print volume ) 
)
```